# Make and Make install

Tags: makefile

I have made some changes to software and when I try to do make and make install, these changes are not being implemented. The output of the code I am getting is that of the older code. I haven't made any changes else where. So where could the problem possibily be?

Comment: Did you do a [./configure](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
make clean
make
make install
```